# Can we have compilers with different int bit-widths?

Tags: compiler-construction, int, bit, cpu-registers

Can we have compilers with int sizes in different bit-widths? For example, are the following possible in any language:

1. 5 bits(not a multiple of 8 bits)
2. More than 64 bits
3. Or something different from 16 bits

Does the data type size have anything to do with the register size.?

I remember reading somewhere that the size of an int can't be greater than register size, but I would like to have a handy reference to this.

Comment: 1. no, but not for that reason; 2. yes; 3. yes (nowadays almost all desktop OSes/compilers treat `int` as a 32-bit value, not 16.). "I read it somewhere size of int cant be greater than register size" - wrong, maybe some sloppy university teacher said that bullsheet.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Why couldn't an integer type be 5 bits? It's illegal in C, which requires `INT_MAX >= 32767`, but in some other language there's no fundamental reason an integer type couldn't be 5 bits wide. It might be grossly inefficient if you don't happen to have a 5-bit CPU. (Ada, for example, permits `type My_Integer is range -16 .. +15;`, though it will probably be stored in at least 8 bits.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Right, I missed that this was language-agnostic. (to my defense, `int` tends to be a type associated with C, and no language having `int` I know of [e. g. Java, C#, etc.] has 5-bit `int`s.)

Comment: It is a fine question.  OP's last few sentences hints this question was possibly about C. He wasn't very clear, so any good answer has to address both C and non-C compilers.  Keith's answer is very good in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The word `int` as the name for an integer type is fairly specific to C and to languages related to it. Pascal and Ada, for example, use the name `Integer` for the most commonly used integer type.

C requires all types (other than bit fields) to be at least 8 bits, and `int` to be at least 16 bits (though it's very commonly 32 these days) -- but you didn't ask about C.

It's certainly possible for a language, or an implementation of a language, to have an integer type of any arbitrary size.

5 bits is an unlikely size for a *fundamental* integer type, but a user-defined integer type (for languages that support such types) is certainly possible. Ada, for example, permits:

```
type Tiny_Integer is range -16 .. +15;
for Tiny_Integer'Size use 5; -- size is 5 bits
```

But an object of that type would, on most machines, probably be stored in 8 or more bits of memory, unless it's a component of a packaged array or record.

I've never heard of a CPU with 5-bit registers, but it's certainly possible. Some old CPUs used 4-bit nibbles; that's a convenient size for pocket calculators that use binary coded decimal, with each digit stored in 4 bits. A language targeted to such a CPU would likely have a 4-bit integer type. (It would probably have larger integer types as well.)

Integers bigger than 64 bits are certainly possible, and are permitted (but not required) by most languages. The gcc C compiler supports 128-bit integer types `__int128` and `unsigned __int128` on some target systems. Many interpreted languages support integers of arbitrary range, often using something like the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/).

> Does the data type size have anything to do with the register size?

Typically, yes, just because making integers fit in registers tends to make for efficient code. Integers bigger (or smaller) than a CPU register might be less efficient.

> I remember reading somewhere that the size of an int can't be greater than register size, ...

That's incorrect. In C, type `int` typically fits in a register (it's intended to have "the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment"), but that's not a requirement. For languages other than C, there are at least as many answers as there are languages.